How do I produce a customizable interaction plot using the estimated marginal means?
I am currently looking at how the effect of two factors (temperature, species) on the duration of the egg stage in insects using a linear model and ANOVA analysis as follows:
## Model
type3.egg <- list(Temperature=contr.sum, Species=contr.sum)
model <- lm(Duration.egg ~ Temperature*Species, data=egg.2, contrasts=type3.egg)
summary(model)
library(car)
Anova(model, type=3)

The interaction between temperature and species was significant so I plotted a simple interaction plot using the emmip() function in the package emmeans where each point is the estimated marginal mean as follows:
library(emmeans)
emmip(model, Species ~ Temperature, type="response", xlab="Temperature (°C)", 
      ylab="Duration of the egg stage (Days)", CI=TRUE)

The plot that was produced is as follows:

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could make the following edits to this plot or knew of an alternative method to producing this same plot as I am aware that the emmip() function does not allow a great deal of customization. The changes I would like to make are:

I would like to remove the background completely (so it is plain white)
I would like to make the points and colors of the lines (and in the legend) black with each line being a different type (e.g. solid and dashed) and the points for each line being different shapes (e.g. circles for A, triangles for B).
I would like the confidence intervals to be a light grey color
Around each point I would like there to be a jitter plot of all of the data points for each combination of species and temperature. If possible, due to overlap, could these be different shapes for each species (or different colors if necessary).

Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

what is the egg.2 dataset? also the emmip function makes a ggplot object so you can probably do all of the cutomizations through ggplot2 code. for example adding +     ggplot2::theme_bw() at the end will make the plot background black and white.

What you want is base graphics. Use emmeans::emmeans to compute EMM beforehand.
Example (using warpbreaks data):
> warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool*tension, data=warpbreaks)
> 
> (emm <- summary(emmeans::emmeans(warp.lm, ~ wool*tension), infer=c(TRUE, TRUE)))
 wool tension emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 A    L         44.6 3.65 48     37.2     51.9  12.218  <.0001
 B    L         28.2 3.65 48     20.9     35.6   7.739  <.0001
 A    M         24.0 3.65 48     16.7     31.3   6.581  <.0001
 B    M         28.8 3.65 48     21.4     36.1   7.891  <.0001
 A    H         24.6 3.65 48     17.2     31.9   6.734  <.0001
 B    H         18.8 3.65 48     11.4     26.1   5.149  <.0001
> 
> png('foo.png', 600, 400)
> par(mar=c(4.5, 4.5, 2, 2))
> with(warpbreaks, 
+      plot(x=jitter(as.integer(as.factor(tension))), y=breaks, 
+           xlab='Temperature (°C)', ylab='Duration of the egg stage (Days)',
+           pch=as.integer(as.factor(wool)), xaxt='n',
+           col='grey')
+      )
> with(warpbreaks, axis(1, at=seq_along(levels(tension)), labels=levels(tension)))
> for (i in seq_along(levels(emm$wool))) {
+   with(subset(emm, wool == levels(emm$wool)[i]),
+        lines(x=as.integer(tension) + switch(i, -.05, .05), 
+              y=emmean, type='o', cex=1.5,
+              lty=as.integer(wool), pch=as.integer(wool))
+   )
+ }
> arrows(as.integer(as.factor(emm$tension)) + c(-.05, .05), emm$lower.CL,
+        as.integer(as.factor(emm$tension)) + c(-.05, .05), emm$upper.CL, 
+        code=3, angle=90, length=.05, col='black', lwd=2, lty=1:2)
> legend('topright', title='Species', levels(emm$wool), cex=1.5,
+                pch=as.integer(emm$wool), lty=as.integer(emm$wool))
> dev.off()



In what section of the code can you make the main emmeans symbols bigger? Also, how would you go about making the legend in the corner bigger?

Also, do you know how I might be able to change the values on the x-axis for temperature to the actual temperatures as they are currently numbered 1-5 (see main question for edit showing picture of plot and code used)

@Insect_biologist In the lines() command we have set type='o' which produces both, points and lines. You can add cex=1.5 to make the symbols 50% larger. You can use the same parameter in legend() to make the entire legend larger.

@Insect_biologist For the xaxis we can use integers as positions and subset the levels, I think they come out as factor out of summary(emmeans(.)) so it should work. Use axis command and set xaxt='n' in plot to avoid automatic drawing. See updated code.

@Insect_biologist Try hard-coded axis(side=1, at=c(1, 2, 3), labels=c(10, 20, 30)) to get the idea what's happening.

Thank you so much for this. I have just noticed that the different line types in the graph are not reflected in the legend. Do you know how to change this so that the line types in the legend are the same as in the graph?

@Insect_biologist Sure, edited, sorry for the oversight. You need to understand the code, so you can fix or alter things for yourself. Cheers!

Run the model again adding plotit=FALSE and save the results. Then use emmip_ggplot to plot the model. This allows you to add further layers to the plot. I use the auto.noise dataset from the emmip package.
noise.lm <- lm(noise ~ size * type, data = auto.noise)

emmip.dat <- emmip(noise.lm, type ~ size, CIs = TRUE, plotit=FALSE)

emmip_ggplot(emmip.dat,  
       linearg = list(col="black", size=1), 
       CIarg = list(lwd = 1, alpha = 1, col="grey70"),
       dotarg = list(col="black", size=4)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(2,"cm")) +
  geom_jitter(data=mutate(auto.noise, tvar=type), aes(x=size, y=noise), col="grey30")



I tried running the code you suggested as follows and the symbols for the jitter plot were the same for both species (see main section of question for edits to show code used). Is there any way I could make the symbols for each species different? I would also like, if possible, to make the jitter plot points less dark.

Sorry - you haven't supplied any data, so I can only guess that your formatting differs from my toy data. For "less dark" points, you can add: col="grey30" in the geom_jitter command as shown in my edited answer.

For your data, Temperature=size, Species = type, and Duration.egg=noise.
